# Byte[r,c,c] to Halcon HObject/HImage to byte[]

Tags: halcon

I am using Zivid.NET, Halcon.NET and ML.NET together. Zivid provides me with a 3D byte array (row, column, channel), Halcon uses `HImages`/`HObjects`, ML.NET functionality expects a 1D byte array (same as `File.ReadAllBytes()`)

So far I used a workaround where:

1. I `save()`'d Zivid's `imageRGBA` as a PNG,
2. which I read with Halcon's `read_image()` that gives me a `HObject`.
3. After some graphical work I saved the `HObject` again as a PNG using `write_image()`.
4. Using `File.ReadAllBytes()` to read that PNG I get the `byte[]` that my ML.NET functionalities expect.

But this is far from ideal with larger amounts of data.

What I need is:

1. a way to convert `byte[r,c,c]` images to `HObject`/`HImage`.
2. a way to convert `HObject`/`HImage` images to `byte[]`.

Halcon's [`read_image()`](https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/13/en/read_image.html) and [`write_image()`](https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/13/en/write_image.html) don't seem to have any options for this and I haven't found anything helpful so far.

Answer (score 1):

To create an HImage object from byte, you need a pointer to an array and then it's simple:

```
public HImage(string type, int width, int height, IntPtr pixelPointer)
```

To get a pointer and acess the data from HImage, the following function is needed:

```
IntPtr HImage.GetImagePointer1(out string type, out int width, out int height)
```

Comment: Using `public HImage(string type, int width, int height, IntPtr pixelPointer)` resulted in a really distorted image when it receives a pointer to 4-channel image data. It did point me in the right direction where I found `GenImage3()` , with this procedure I could get the correct image, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To convert from Zivid.NET's byte[r,c,c] to HImage one can:

```cs
var byteArr = imgRGBA.ToByteArray();

byte[,] redByteArray = new byte[1200, 1920];
byte[,] greenByteArray = new byte[1200, 1920];
byte[,] blueByteArray = new byte[1200, 1920];

for (int row = 0; row < 1200; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < 1920; col++)
    {
        redByteArray[row, col] = byteArr[row, col, 0];
        greenByteArray[row, col] = byteArr[row, col, 1];
        blueByteArray[row, col] = byteArr[row, col, 2];
    }

GCHandle pinnedArray_red = GCHandle.Alloc(redByteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer_red = pinnedArray_red.AddrOfPinnedObject();

GCHandle pinnedArray_green = GCHandle.Alloc(greenByteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer_green = pinnedArray_green.AddrOfPinnedObject();

GCHandle pinnedArray_blue = GCHandle.Alloc(blueByteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer_blue = pinnedArray_blue.AddrOfPinnedObject();

GenImage3(out HObject imgHImage, "byte", 1920, 1200, pointer_red, pointer_green, pointer_blue);

pinnedArray_red.Free();
pinnedArray_green.Free();
pinnedArray_blue.Free();
```

Still working on the second part..
A better / more efficient method is very welcome.